# Terms and Conditions link redirecting to checkout page in Opencart

Tags: opencart

When my Opencart website is moved from http:// to https://, I have changed
http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js to https://ws.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js
Now from the checkout page, when I click on Terms and Condition (Payment Method) link, the page is redirect and loading to the same checkout page. How to correct this issue?

Comment: Have you any errors in your console log? can you show us your site?

Comment: Can you please add your site link on which you exactly facing this issue ?

Comment: https://www.the-vacmaster.ca/checkout/, this is the website link, and it shows error in console as Blocked Content : http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js